# How to run Xcode 7 and 8 at the same time?

Tags: xcode, xcode7, xcode8

Is there a way to run Xcode 7 and Xcode 8 at the same time? I have 2 different projects. Both need to be worked on different versions as of now.

Comment: I am already try but Xcode 8 open that Xcode 7 doesn't open(crash)

Comment: If you have to Xcode apps in you mac you can. Check open with option at xcodeproject

Comment: This thread might help [Installing two versions of Xcode on a Mac](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/19218) (from the Apple Developer forum). Running them in parallel though, could probably cause any number of problems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you could do is to:

1. Downloaded Xcode 7 from Apple Developer site
2. Open the downloaded .dmg for Xcode 7 and drag the Xcode.app to your desktop
3. Rename this Xcode.app to Xcode-7.app
4. Now you should be able to run Xcode 7 and Xcode 8 (downloaded from App Store or Apple developer site)

Answer (score 2):

And to run Applications on iOS10 Devices from XCode 7.x your should do:

Copy that folder:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/10.0
```

To your existing 7.3.1 Installation Folder

```
/Applications/Xcode-7.3.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/
```